# install GitLab on a server running Windows 7

Tags: windows, gitlab

I need to install GitLab on a server running Windows 7, but I'm blocked at this line. The documentation doesn't really helping me. The following is from my command prompt:

> ```
> C:\GitLab-Runner>gitlab-runner.exe register
> Please enter gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
> https://gitlab.com
> Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
> ```

Where can I find this token?

Comment: You're attempting to install the **GitLab CI Runner**, not *GitLab* itself. This is a major distinction!

Comment: maybe this is the problem, I need to install a gitlab itself (like github) so I can do it, right ?

Comment: @Euphor08: It is not supported to install GitLab under Windows, see my edited answer. Use a VM with Linux for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're attempting to install the **GitLab Runner** which is used to run your jobs and send the results to a **GitLab** which is a server. As you're talking about **GitLab** running at a server you have to install that and **not the Runner**.

But it is not supported to install GitLab on Windows, see [here in the GitLab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-install-gitlab-on-windows/32). They recommend to use Linux in a virtual machine for that if you want it on Windows.

> In all seriousness this is something that will probably never be supported.

---

Nevertheless to get the needed **project registration token** follow these steps [described here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#registering-a-specific-runner-with-a-project-registration-token). Also there is a discussion about it [on GitHub](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci-runner/issues/77).

> To create a specific Runner without having admin rights to the GitLab instance, visit the project you want to make the Runner work for in GitLab:
>
> 1. Go to **Settings ➔ Pipelines** to obtain the token
> 2. [Register the Runner](http://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/)

Further the process of registering the GitLab Runner which is actually what you're doing is described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html).